# Time Dilation of one frame wrt other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, time-dilation

Suppose A and B are two objects , with B travelling at some constant velocity v wrt A. After B covers some distance, A(the person in A) notes in his clock as 30sec elapsed. Then from A's perspective, B's clock will be slow , suppose it's 15sec(from A's perspective). What will be the time seen by an observer in B in a clock in B(After B travels that distance). Will it be 15sec ,the time as seen by A, or it'll be 30sec-as time is going normally for the person in B.

Comment: Please Clarify..

Comment: You seem to be asking a question that you answer earlier in the question. You say that observer B records a time of 30 seconds, but then ask what time observer B sees.

Comment: It's worth looking at the (many!)  links in the "Related" sidebar here. Everybody hits this confusions, and that is because everyone comes in believing things about the nature of time that simply aren't true. (They are approximately true at day-to-day velocities and people get to treat those approximate symmetries as exact.)

Comment: I think you need to read a book (or webpage) about Special Relativity.  Or (as dmckee suggests) look at a related qn, eg Why don't two observers' clocks measure the same time between the same events? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10656

Answer (score -1):

You need to think about time dilation as a Warping of Space relative to either velocity or mass. A massive object will bend space-time, so that light is able to travel with the least resistence to time or the path of "least time". which makes it the fastest "object" in the Universe since Space-Time will always adjust for it to maintain that "Speed Limit of the Universe".

Another way I think about it, which may be wrong, is that all matter absorbs or reflects light at the same speed.

Feynman is a good source to use. http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_26.html

Also, time dilation differs relative to the acceleration of the object and its relativistic mass.

[Why does the (relativistic) mass of an object increase when its speed approaches that of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/why-does-the-relativistic-mass-of-an-object-increase-when-its-speed-approaches)

What you're looking for is time dilation due to Gravitation and Motion together.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation