# An experimentation on time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, time, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

In the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev9zrt__lec from 03:00 to 05:00

I hope that both the clocks would read the same equal amount ,say,1 revolution, in measuring the time elapsed for the flash to return to the laser fired.

And the both Sarah and Adam may feel the time elapsed to be different in their own perspectives which might have arised from "the speed of light is same for all observers.

I think i am right upto this extent.

Now, Is time dilation an illusive phenomenon in which one may feel "a one single tick of a clock" which can be "one minute" for another one WHILE for both of them, the clock is universal and runs at same pace ???

Why do Sarah and Adam feel the time elapsed to be different ?? in what way ?

Comment: Hi Vinayak. I closed your question because it was asking *Is time dilation an illusive phenomenon*, which is a duplicate or an earlier question. Your edit suggests you are really asking about why time dilation occurs i.e. what is the mechanism. If so perhaps you could edit your question to clarify precisely what you are asking. Note that there have already been questions asking about the mechanism of time dilation.

Comment: The new question seems like a dupe of many questions, for example there is [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10656/) & it's linked questions.